# I'm getting an error when importing a .DAT file using read.fortran

Tags: r, fortran

I am trying to import a .DAT file of cancer related deaths in Hiroshima and Nagasaki from the 1980s. I have looked at various ways to read fortran in R, but none of them have had similar error messages I am getting. The data source gave me Fortran formats of:

(2I3,I4,F7.1,I5,I4,F10.2,26I4)

or

(2F3.0,F4.0,F7.0,F5.0,F4.0,F10.0,26F4.0).

I tried this code:

```
read.fortran("R10CANCR.DAT", c("2I3","I4","F7.1","I5","I4","F10.2","26I4"))
```

when I do this, it gives me an error:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec
>   = dec, : scan() expected 'an integer', got ''

What can I do to fix this?

The original data is available on registration from this site:

https://www.rerf.or.jp/en/library/data-en/lss10cm/

Comment: It would be really, really helpful if you could post the file, or at least a sample of it (looks like it's [here](https://www.rerf.or.jp/en/library/data-en/lss10cm/)?)

Comment: The problem looks to be a final row which has a single character in it. If you drop the final row, it imports fine for me - `canc <- read.fortran("R10CANCR.DAT", c("2I3","I4","F7.1","I5","I4","F10.2","26I4"), n=1280)` . A good way to debug these problems is to use `x <- readLines("R10CANCR.DAT")` first, and then take a look at the plain text file that is imported.

Answer (score 4):

I recovered the file from [here](https://www.rerf.or.jp/en/library/data-en/lss10cm/) (registered, downloaded, unzipped, didn't otherwise mess with the contents at all).  As @thelatemail says, the problem is a Ctrl-Z in the final line.  One easy way to fix it is to read the text and then write all but the last line to a corrected file:

```
r0 <- readLines("R10CANCR.DAT")
writeLines(r0[1:(length(r0)-1)],"R10cancrfix.dat")
```

**However**: I'd be careful with those suggested Fortran format strings. The README says

> All fields are separated by at least one blank so the file can
>   easily be read using a FORTRAN free-format read.

which suggests that good ol' `read.table()` should work. When I tried this, I found discrepancies between the `read.fortran()` and `read.table()` results (for one of the format strings, not the other), and the following example suggests that one of the suggested format strings is inconsistent with the spacing in the data file.

```
r <- read.table("r10cancrfix.dat")
fstr <- c("2I3","I4","F7.1","I5","I4","F10.2","26I4")
fstr2 <- c("2F3.0","F4.0","F7.0","F5.0","F4.0","F10.0","26F4.0") 
r2 <- read.fortran("r10cancrfix.dat",fstr)
r3 <- read.fortran("r10cancrfix.dat",fstr2)
all.equal(r,r3) ## TRUE
all.equal(r,r2)
## [1] "Component “V4”: Mean relative difference: 0.9" 
## [2] "Component “V7”: Mean relative difference: 0.99"
```

What's going on?

```
r$V4[9]  ## first non-zero value in this column
## [1] 3.3
r2$V4[9]
## [1] 0.33
```

This is what the original file contains:

```
cat(r0[9])
```

> 0 0    5    3.3   52   1   6140.30   5   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

The fourth value is 3.3, not 0.33. If we are to believe that the human interpretation of this file is correct, then the first Fortran format string is incorrect.

More evidence that these should be 3.3 and not 0.33 (and so forth) is in the README file:

> DOSE        11:17   T65DR total exposure kerma.  The classmarks used are city-specific dose group averages.  The eight dose groups are 0, 1-9, 10-49, 50-99, 100-199, 200-299, 300-399, and 400+ centigray(rad). ... Average doses are given in centiGray.

So it makes sense that the average of the 1-9 centigray group would be 3.3, not 0.33 centigray ...

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find the file online, and following the readme, I get this result:

```r
df <- read.fortran("~/R10CANCR.DAT", 
                   c("2F3.0", "F4.0", "F7.0", "F5.0", "F4.0", "F10.0", "26F4.0"))
names(df) <-  c("CITY", "SEX", "AGEATB", "DOSE", "TIME", "INDEX", "PYR", "ALLDEATH", 
                "ALLDIS", "ALLNEO", "ALLMAL", "LEUK", "NONLEUK", "DIGEST", "ESOPH", 
                "STOMACH", "COLON", "RECTUM", "LIVER", "GALLBLDR", "PANCREAS", 
                "OTHRDIG", "RESP", "LUNG", "FBREAST", "FGENITAL", "CERVIX", "OVARY", 
                "PROSTATE", "URINARY", "LYMPHOMA", "MYELOMA", "OTHRCA")

dplyr::as_tibble(df)
# A tibble: 1,280 x 33
    CITY   SEX AGEATB  DOSE  TIME INDEX    PYR ALLDEATH ALLDIS ALLNEO ALLMAL  LEUK NONLEUK DIGEST ESOPH
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0      5   0      52     1 10979.        9      7      1      1     1       0      0     0
 2     0     0      5   0      56     2 10287.       12      4      0      0     0       0      0     0
 3     0     0      5   0      60     3 10223        17      7      0      0     0       0      0     0
 4     0     0      5   0      64     4 10168.       13      6      0      0     0       0      0     0
 5     0     0      5   0      68     5 10119.       13      7      2      2     1       1      1     0
 6     0     0      5   0      72     6 10061.       13      9      2      2     1       1      1     0
 7     0     0      5   0      76     7  9995.       16     13      3      3     0       3      2     0
 8     0     0      5   0      80     8  9924.       16     13      1      1     0       1      0     0
 9     0     0      5   3.3    52     1  6140.        5      3      0      0     0       0      0     0
10     0     0      5   3.3    56     2  5750.       10      4      0      0     0       0      0     0
# ... with 1,270 more rows, and 18 more variables: STOMACH <dbl>, COLON <dbl>, RECTUM <dbl>,
#   LIVER <dbl>, GALLBLDR <dbl>, PANCREAS <dbl>, OTHRDIG <dbl>, RESP <dbl>, LUNG <dbl>, FBREAST <dbl>,
#   FGENITAL <dbl>, CERVIX <dbl>, OVARY <dbl>, PROSTATE <dbl>, URINARY <dbl>, LYMPHOMA <dbl>,
#   MYELOMA <dbl>, OTHRCA <dbl>
```

Comment: Huh. Can you post the link where you found the file? I'm wondering why I had format problems and you didn't (I downloaded the file directly from the reference source, and didn't mess around with it other than removing the last line)

Comment: @BenBolker - seems to be two sets of formats given here - https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rerf.or.jp%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F09%2Freadme.html

Comment: @BenBolker yes, I also got the file from the reference source, but as thelatemail says, there are two formats given. I just tried the other one and it worked first time.

Comment: I would still be interested to see where you retrieved the file from.  You don't mention having to get rid of a terminal Ctrl-Z, and if you are getting identical results from the two different format strings, that doesn't match my experience (see my edited question above).

Comment: Could this possibly be platform-dependent (newline/file termination characters)?

Comment: @BenBolker  I got the file from the same place you did, unzipped it and that was all.  The file still has a byte 0x1a in the last line, but both Fortran formats work on my setup. I'm on a Win32 work PC

Comment: @BenBolker if you trace the call stack to find out how read.fortran works, `read.fortran` calls `read.fwf`, which calls `read.table`, which calls `scan`. When I run `scan` on the file, I don't get an error _but_ if I read the file into memory as a raw vector and convert it to character, I get the error trying to `scan` that string, _unless_ I remove the last byte.

Comment: I suspect a Windows vs other platforms difference.